# Are magazines (journals) "Scientific American" and "Popular Science" peer reviewed?

Tags: journals, peer-review

[Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Scientist) says that New Scientist publishes articles which are not peer-reviewed.

But I found no information about "Scientific American" (SciAm) and "Popular Science" (PopSci).

Comment: The question in the title (Are these journals peer reviewed?) is different to the one in the body of your question (Is there an algorithm to find out if they are reviewed?). Can you clarify which you are asking?

Comment: Why should they? They don't publish research papers.

Comment: "Journal" doesn't even seem to be the appropriate word. As SciAm's website states, they're a magazine, not a journal.

Comment: Are these journals? I don't think so.

Comment: Where exactly does WP say that about *New Scientist*? (I couldn't find it in the article). And how do they word it? Worded like you do, it almost seems that any paper sent in is published, without even having a look at it.

Comment: @JAB New Scientist *used* to be a magazine, years ago. Now, its mostly random noise. To quote from its own website, https://www.newscientist.com/in209-guide-for-freelancers/: "New Scientist is not intended as required reading for professional scientists, as a public service or as an educational tool." As an example of a feature written by a freelance journalist that they *did* publish, they give this: "In this feature I will look at voodoo death and tell the story of an Alabama man rendered near death after a late night argument with a witch doctor." Yeah, right....

Comment: @alephzero wrong person quoted

Comment: On New Scientist:  link from Russian wikipedia article reads: "Editors of non-peer-reviewed journals - New Scientist included - have a far greater responsibility than those in the peer-reviewed world to filter out distortions."

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From the Scientific American [website](http://www.nature.com/scientificamerican/information/submit.html):

> Generally speaking, SCIENTIFIC AMERICAN presents ideas that have already been published in the peer-reviewed technical literature. We do not publish new theories or results of original research.
>
> Please allow six to eight weeks for the review process.

From this and other submission instructions on that page I conclude that the manuscripts undergo a general review that is probably aimed at accuracy and style, which is different than typical scientific peer-review of original research.

No scientific peer-review is mentioned in the relevant page on the Popular Science [website](http://www.popsci.com/writers-guidelines) either.

Comment: It's *review* in the sense of editorial review, not peer review, in other words.

Answer (score 15):

Neither journal is a peer-reviewed scientific journal, both are popular science journals. So (1) they don't publish original research and (2) the aim of the review process is completely different. In particular, reviewing is done to ensure that the article is suitable for the scientifically minded public, i.e. avoids complicated math and difficult terminology, but hardly to scrutinize correctness (or even originality).

Comment: Re: #2: Peer-reviewed journals *also* typically referee to ensure that the article is suitable for the intended audience. It's just that their intended audience is different.

Comment: @Makyen Yes, that was a slip of the pen. I have changed "refereeing" to "reviewing". Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

These are not academic journals, but magazines which report on stories of interest to the public.  They source their stories from peer-reviewed academic papers from various journals.

That is, they are not the primary place of publication or the original paper for any of the research presented within; they are simply reporting on research published first elsewhere.

So.  Is the research they cover peer-reviewed?  By and large, yes.  But it has been peer-reviewed elsewhere, in another form - and has been reported on by a journalist specialising in science, who did not write the original publication or do the experimentation themself but is seeking to expose it to a larger audience.

You are given the opportunity to consult the original publication; each story that originates from a scientific publication should cite its source.